# Apache 404 Error - Drupal

Tags: javascript, html, apache, drupal, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues transferring my project over from my MAMP Pro to a live VPS server. When doing this transaction, i copied over everything (including the database) and everything is now connected.

However, apart from the frontpage, all the pages are broken. Broken like:

> 404 Not Found The server can not find the requested page:
>
> ***.**.**.*/returns-calculator (port 80) Please forward this error screen to* ..**.*'s WebMaster.
>
> Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server
>   at 212.48.65.2 Port 80

1. RewriteLog: http://pastebin.com/j0QLePH7
2. ApacheLog: http://pastebin.com/m06D97s7
3. .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/LEHugCwi

I have confirmed from the hosting company that mod_rewrite is enabled and automatically enabled for each and everyone of the website.

Can you please help?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Please show your .htaccess file.

Comment: Hello, http://pastebin.com/LEHugCwi thats the htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

After 3 days of finding the solution, i rebuilt the vps again and a simple `RewriteBase /~name` in the .htacess did it.